# Member function pointer wrapper using variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

I'm currently trying to compile my code using Visual C++ 2013 and want to take the advantage of variadic templates. I have several classes which wrap the function pointer - several versions for different number of arguments.

The wrapper for a member function with one argument is the following:

```
template <typename T, T> struct proxy;

template <typename T, typename R, typename Arg0, R(T::*mf)(Arg0)>
struct proxy<R(T::*)(Arg0), mf>
{
    proxy(T& host) : m_Host(host) {}

    template <typename Arg0>
    R call(Arg0&& arg0)
    {
        return (m_Host.*mf)(std::forward<Arg0>(arg0));
    }

private:
    proxy& operator=(const proxy&);
    T& m_Host;
};
```

Let's have some test class:

```
class SomeHost
{
public:
    int SomeGetter() { return 42; }
    void SomeSetter(int var) { m_Var = var;}
private:
    int m_Var;
};
```

and a test case:

```
void test()
{
    SomeHost obj;
    proxy<void(SomeHost::*)(int), &SomeHost::SomeSetter> g(obj);
    g.call(5);
}
```

Everything works fine so far. I rewrote the proxy class using variadic template:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args, R(T::*mf)(Args...)>
struct proxy<R(T::*)(Args...), mf>
{
    proxy(T& host) : m_Host(host) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    R call(Args&&... args)
    {
        return (m_Host.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    proxy& operator=(const proxy&);
    T& m_Host;
};
```

Using the variadic template, Visual C++ 2013 shows me several compiler errors coming from the test function:

```
file.cpp(79): error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__thiscall SomeHost::* )(void)'
1> None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type: see reference to class template instantiation 'proxy<void (__thiscall SomeHost::* )(int),SomeHost::SomeSetter>' being compiled
1>file.cpp(79): error C2973: 'proxy<R(__thiscall T::* )(Args...),mf>' : invalid template argument 'overloaded-function'
1>file.cpp(40) : see declaration of 'proxy<R(__thiscall T::* )(Args...),mf>'
```

I also tested the template with the SomeHost::SomeGetter() and it worked without any problems.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Fixing up the `Args` parameters, your code has no issues on `gcc` [See it live here](http://ideone.com/rCCuUO), and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abf9db8f161e7ed1). I can likewise vouch it works on clang.

Comment: Note that you shadowing `Arg0` (`Args`) in your `call` method.

Comment: I'm curious: what's the real use case for this?

Comment: I haven't provided the entire code, just extracted a problematic part. It's used to implement  Friendship / Attorney-Client pattern.