# Member function pointer wrapper using variadic template (gcc, clang)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member

Why does the following code not compile under either gcc or clang:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void bar(int) {}
};

template< class T, typename ...Args, void(T::*Member)(Args...) >
void member_dispatch(Args&&... args, void* userdata)
{
    T* obj = static_cast<T*>(userdata);
    (obj->*Member)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    member_dispatch<Foo, int, &Foo::bar>(1, &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

See e.g. [here](https://ideone.com/KPHwkH).

This question can possibly be merged with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283072/member-function-pointer-wrapper-using-variadic-template) one, though here I get unclear compilation errors from gcc and clang (instead of VS).

Comment: Why can't you simply solve your problem with standard `std::function` and `std::bind` (or lambdas)? Or like almost all standard library functions and classes that needs callable objects, by using a single `typename` template argument for the function type?

Comment: This is for interfacing with C libraries that use callbacks in the form of `void callback(<some params>, void* userdata)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you explicitly specify the types, a parameter pack is greedy. `&Foo::bar` will be parsed as part of `typename ...Args`, which causes the error.

The correct way to write this is to put it in the function parameter list, instead of a non-type template parameter.

```
template< class T, typename ...Args>
void member_dispatch(Args&&... args, void(T::*Member)(Args...), void* userdata)
{
    T* obj = static_cast<T*>(userdata);
    (obj->*Member)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    member_dispatch<Foo, int>(1, &Foo::bar, &foo);
    return 0;
}
```

**A Better Way:**

It would be better to take advantage of C++'s template argument deduction. But here you doesn't put the parameter pact at the end of a function parameter list, which is a non-deduced context. So I suggest you re-order it, so that you don't need to specify the template argument:

```
template<class T, class K, typename ...Args>
void member_dispatch(K T::*ptr, void* userdata, Args&&... args)
{
    T* obj = static_cast<T*>(userdata);
    (obj->*ptr)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    member_dispatch(&Foo::bar, &foo, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No wait. Empty parameter pack. You need the `int`. I think it'd be better to suggest a better alternative to the OP. In terms of ordering the types and parameters.

Comment: @StoryTeller I missed something. My last comment is wrong. But still non-deduced context, because pact is not the last in function parameter list

Comment: Yeah, that's what my comment is going for too. Ultimately, it'd be better to rearrange things to allow for as much deduction as possible. Utilize C++ to it's full power and all those niceties.

Comment: For my use case I can't pass the member function as a parameter, it needs to be compiled in as a non-type template parameter somehow

Comment: Anyway, I guess the answer itself appears correct, thanks. According to cppreference "In a function template, the template parameter pack may appear earlier in the list provided that all following parameters can be deduced from the function arguments" and I missed that condition

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class template instead of a function template.
There has also been a std syntax proposal "template << auto x >> " for none-type template parameters. Proper implementation will simplify your library syntax.